# Apache2 server security and magento

Tags: magento-1.9, security, server-setup, apache2

I want to use this in my pre conf for the server

```
Header unset Content-Security-Policy
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
Header unset X-Content-Security-Policy
Header add X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'"
Header unset X-WebKit-CSP
Header add X-WebKit-CSP "default-src 'self'"
```

issue is this blocks jquery fontawesome google fonts etc and messes up my design anyone know how to tweak this to allow for imported fonts jquery etc. banging my head on this

Answer (score 2):

Use Access-Control-Allow-Origin for each resource you want to use?

`Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://anotherdomain.com"`